# Should I insist on asking the recruiter about the company technology stack?

Tags: communication, job-offer, recruitment, technology

I have been through a situation where recruiters contact me on Linkedin saying that they stopped by my profile and find that I'm a perfect match for a vacancy at their company.

I try to ask more about the job, any job description, company location, technology stack, ... etc, usually most of the recruiters does not have much information about the technology stack or specific task list that awaits the chosen candidate, all they want is pushing me to send my resume and then everything will become clear once I'm in the interview room with the IT manager.

So, my question is: Should I insist on knowing more about the tasks, and technology stack?

Thank you!

Amir Iskander

Comment: I would suggest that you wait at least 24 hours before accepting an answer.  Many of our top folks are still sleeping at the moment.

Comment: I would be very surprised to find a candidate in front of me in the interview room who didn't know anything about the technology stack we were using.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Should I insist on knowing more about the tasks, and technology stack?

Yes you absolutely should know the **technology stack** before any interview is set up.  You should also verify that the **salary range** of the position will work for you.  There is no point in wasting your time having a technical interview that in now way will match your skill set.  Same with the salary range.

LinkedIn has been pretty good to me overall from a recruiter perspective.  You have to be *careful of course in giving out details*.

Comment: To elaborate on the last point (I guess): (I've heard) recruiters don't want to tell you too much in case you apply for the role directly before they've had the chance to send your details through to the company, which obviously screws them over. But they should obviously at least tell you enough to pique your interest.

Comment: @Dukeling Exactly.  You have to get enough basic info to know there is at least a shot of the opportunity working out.  Salary, Tech Stack, and location are just a few of the items I would verify before sharing information.

Comment: I personally wouldn't give my information to **anyone** who wouldn't give me the technology stack. Either the recruiter is unscrupulous or incompetent. The only semi-legitimate reason for a recruiter not to **need** to know your stack (and thus share the one being sought) is if they're building a database for future use. As I said, I find that to be *semi*-legitimate and I wouldn't be giving my resume in that case unless I already felt good about that recruiter or his company from prior interactions.

Comment: @ChristopherEstep Excellent points.  I have a network of recruiters I liked working with in the past that I reach out to when the need arises.

Answer (score 1):

> So, my question is: Should I insist on knowing more about the tasks, and technology stack?

You most definitely should ask them. Not (neccesarily) because it's super important to know, but because of this:

> saying that they stopped by my profile and find that I'm a perfect match for a vacancy at their company.

If they can't tell you exactly what the technology stack is and why that's a great fit for you, they're just blowing smoke up your butt. In which case, you should take their opinion on how good a fit you are with a tablespoon of salt and just ask them for the vacancy so you can judge for yourself before you waste any time on setting up interviews.

There are a lot of recruiters that will have "the perfect job" for you every week because they don't know what they're talking about and they're hoping to hook people with flattery. 
There are also some recruiters that really do know what they're talking about, can tell you exactly why that job is perfect for you.

Until you figure out which of the two types of recruiter you're talking to, "this job is perfect for you" is just noise. Asking "why?" will show you pretty quickly, so that's definitely a first step.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should. This the recruiter job - introduce you to a position details, get interested and so forth. Not just resend your CV. Otherwise, you could apply directly.

Answer (score -1):

> Should I insist on knowing more about the tasks, and technology stack?

You can decide if you should or you shouldn't, based on how important the details are for you.

If they are important, ask for a phone interview first and ask about tasks and technologies as much as you like.

Don't expect LinkedIn contacts themselves to know much.

Answer (score -2):

Be wary of LinkedIn recruiters. They may just be phishing for your personal information. Some are legitimate. I know many friends who found jobs this way.

For me, as a software developer, there's a few things I want to know before I'll even consider working there. What software do they use? What languages? Is there a methodology that is followed? What version control do they use? Right now I'm dealing with my company not supporting Windows 10 and it's really frustrating.

You should insist on knowing more. But you should insist on knowing more from the person who knows the information you want. Getting technical information filtered through a recruiter is next to useless. If you're interested in the job, apply. What's stopping you? You can always say no after you finish the interview.

Comment: I wouldn't think the danger from a LinkedIn recruiter is any greater than any other recruiter.  LinkedIn is supposed to be a professional networking site, after all.  However, that doesn't mean that they actually have a position that they just happen to think OP is a great fit for, as opposed to trying to add, generally, to their pool of candidates in a very broad classification.

Comment: Agree wiht @PoloHoleSet. LinkedIn and Indeed have been my go to's for years when needing a job.

Comment: I can't disagree enough with the statement "Be wary of LinkedIn recruiters" in that there's no reason to single them out and gives the false impression that recruiters found on that site are generally less reputable than those found elsewhere.  I've found that not to be the case. Just treat them like any other, i.e. don't think "they're on LinkedIn so they must trustworthy" and you'll be fine.

Comment: I agree with this totally.  recruiters who work by trolling social sites and "business social sites" are usually pretty mediocre, "shotgun approach" outfits.

Comment: If you think that there is no risk in handing personal information to someone claiming to be a LinkedIn recruiter, you're a moron. You're also a moron for downvoting this answer because of your stupid opinion.